# Stored Procedure with less parameters than associated object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure (`sp_create_user`) in my database that creates a user in my `Users` table. This is my stored procedure definition:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_create_user
    @Username nvarchar(50),
    @Password nvarchar(50),
AS
BEGIN
    -- SQL STATMENTS
END
```

My `User` object in c# is this:

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my EF mapping the User entity insert to that stored procedure:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().MapToStoredProcedures(
  s =>
      s.Insert(i => i.HasName("sp_create_user"))
);
```

When I try to execute a new creation of user I get an exception that the number of parameters sent to the stored procedure is too big. After tracing the query, I see that it sends to the stored procedure all the fields that the `User` class has.

How can I tell EF to send only the relevant fields for the stored procedure?

Comment: Side note if this is for **SQL Server**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Can't you just add the parameters to the SP? :)

Comment: That's what I ended up doing :(

Answer (score 1):

```
...
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]
public int UserId { get; set; }

public string Username { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }

[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]
public string LastName { get; set; }
...
```

You can also try the following if you don't want to modify the class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Ignore(u => u.UserId);
```

Comment: is there a way to define it in the mapping without interfering with  the entity class?

Comment: What will "Ignore" do? will it have effects later on on regular EF update? because on update I would like to send some of the fields I don't send on SP insert